# How can I restructure my files so that I can more easily compile separate programs with the same names?

Tags: makefile

When doing competitive programming I have each problem in a self-contained directory with tests and solution, similar to the following:

```
problem_a/
  tests/
    default.in default.out
  main.c
```

I also like being able to compile the solution (always a single file) and run it by feeding it the input file and diffing the result with the output file via a simple command line command.  I usually use something akin to the following:

```
make main && (./main < tests/default.in | diff tests/default.out - ; rm main)
```

Now I want to be able to have multiple solutions (of different programming languages) in the same directory.  For example, to add a `main.cpp`.  However, this conflicts with the above command because `make` always prefers the default C rule over the CPP rule.

Is the most realistic solution for this just to postfix the filenames with an extra `_c` and `_cpp` descriptor?  The purist in me thinks this redundant and hopes for a better way, perhaps to be able to reorder the default rules of `make`?

Comment: Put the programs each in a source file such as `prog01.c`, `prog02.c` or `q1.c`, `q2.c`, or some other suitable naming scheme.  You can now type `make prog01` to build `prog01` from `prog01.c`, etc.  The testing can be automated too: create input `prog01.input` and `prog01.out`.  Then you can write a 'link and test' rule in the `makefile` so that after the link succeeds, the test is run automatically.

Comment: If you have `main.c` and `main.cc`, then what do you want `make main` to do?

Comment: @Beta I don't know, specify a flag to make to determine which default rule to use?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I like your suggestion but it does not help me in having solutions in different languages for a single problem.

Comment: So you want to invoke Make two different ways, to build two different things. Why do you want them to have the same name?

Comment: @Beta Because I can't think of anything better than [main1.c, main2.cpp] or [main_c.c, main_cpp.cpp], the former being ugly and confusing, and the latter being annoyingly repetitive.  Perhaps I should work on my naming skills?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a directory for solutions so that when running `make` there are no name clashes:

```
problem_A/
  solutions/
    cpp/
      main.cpp
    ansi-c/
      main.c
  tests/
    default.in
    default.out
```

Then I wrote a simple script to be able to build and test together:

```
  3 BINFILE=./solutions/$1/main
  4 INFILE=./tests/$2.in
  5 OUTFILE=./tests/$2.out
  6 
  7 make $BINFILE && ($BINFILE < $INFILE | diff $OUTFILE - ; rm $BINFILE)
```

This script can be run as follows:

`cp-test ansi-c default`

Not the most elegant solution ever, but it works for now.  Any other suggestions would be great.